# Asymptotics of $\sum _{k=1}^n \sum _{j=1}^n \frac{j k}{j+k}$

Tags: summation

I'm asked to find a simple asymptotical estimation of $\displaystyle \sum _{p=1}^n \sum _{q=1}^n \frac{p q}{p+q}$.

I rewrote the sum as $\displaystyle  \sum _{k=2}^{2 n}\sum_{p+q=k}\frac{pq}{p+q}= \sum _{k=2}^{2 n} \sum _{p=1}^{k-1} \frac{p (k-p)}{k}$.

But it seems that $$\displaystyle \sum _{p=1}^n \sum _{q=1}^n \frac{p q}{p+q} \neq \sum _{k=2}^{2 n} \sum _{p=1}^{k-1} \frac{p (k-p)}{k}$$

What have I done wrong ?

Comment: When $k>n$ you still need to ensure that $1\leq p,q\leq n$, which your second sum does not represent. You need $p,k-p\leq n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$\sum_{p=1}^{n}\sum_{q=1}^{n}\frac{pq}{p+q}\\=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{\nu=1}^{k-1}\nu(k-\nu)+\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{\nu=1}^{n}\nu(n+1-\nu)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k}\sum_{\nu=k}^n\nu(n+k-\nu)\\=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{k^2-1}{6}+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(n-k+1)(n(n-1)+4kn+k+k^2)}{6(n+k)}\\
=\frac{2}{3}(1-\log 2)\,n^3+o(n^3).$$

Comment: $S=\dfrac{4n^3+7n^2+3n+1}6+\dfrac{2n^3+3n^2+n}3\cdot\Big(H_n-H_{2n}\Big)$.

Comment: @Jack thanks for another insightful answer. I got the same result as you with a different, longer method (I got first an asymptotic estimation of $S_{n+1}-S_n$, and then summed).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot $p \le n$ and $q \le n$.  So $p$ should go from $\max(1, k-n)$ to $\min(n, k-1)$.